# Excel 2010 VBA alternate row color on changing range starting with A5

Tags: vba, excel

In my Excel worksheet I need to apply alternate colors on a specific range that will always start in A5 and end in column X, however the number of lines will change each time the report is ran.

At the end of the first range I need to move down 2 rows and apply alternate row color to the 4 rows.

I found the following code on stackoverflow but so far I can only get row A5 to highlight.

```
Sub AlternateRowColors()
    Dim LastRow As Long

        'LastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown) 'Row From original code

    'Find the last used row in a Column: column A in this example
    'Dim LastRow As Long
    With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End With

For Each Cell In Range("A5:x" & LastRow) ''change range accordingly
    If Cell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then ''highlights row 2,4,6 etc|= 0 highlights 1,3,5
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 ''color to preference
    Else
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ''color to preference or remove
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

I have been trying to figure this out for two days now, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please debug your code. What is the value of `LastRow`?

Comment: Basically your problem is this: the value of `LastRow` is not what you expect nor want it to be. Why this is the case depends on the values in `ActiveSheet`.

Comment: Right now X128 is my last cell and is blank, but A128 is not blank. The next time I run this report the last cell could contain data. I am sorry to say, but I am not sure how to "debug" my code is Excel. I stepped through it using F8, but I don't think that is the same.

Comment: I added a MsgBox and ran the code and it is telling me that LastRow is 136, but I would expect it be 128. there is a blank row between the two sections or ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I completely understand your problem, however it *sounds* as though it's to do with an inaccurate LastRow. Try this method instead. I've commented out your current LastRow method and entered a new one. If you want the absolute last row in your sheet, regardless of which column has the last item of data, then this will help you:

```
Sub AlternateRowColors()
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        'LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End With

For Each Cell In Range("A5:x" & LastRow) ''change range accordingly
    If Cell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then ''highlights row 2,4,6 etc|= 0 highlights 1,3,5
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 ''color to preference
    Else
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ''color to preference or remove
    End If
Next Cell
End Sub
```

---

Additional edit: You asked about stopping the highlight 8 rows before the LastRow. We could change the value of the LastRow after establishing it. Simply add the following two lines in the middle of the code (after the End With, and before the For Each loop):

```
LastRow = LastRow - 8
If LastRow < 5 Then LastRow = 5
```

The first line changes the LastRow variable; the second line checks if the LastRow value is now less than our intended starting row (row 5). If it is less, then it changes it to 5, as 5 is the minimum (starts on row 5, ends on row 5 or later).

---

Additional edit 2: You say that the row below the "LastRow" is a merged row and would not be highlighted, but the next 4 rows will have a different highlight color... try out the code below. The main addition is the last line of code which colours the single range, the four lines as you describe. However to use this line of code I had to reference the genuine LastRow, and so I had to change the middle of the script - it now creates a new 'LastRowNew' for the purpose of colouring the alternate rows, as it did before.

Hopefully this is what you need now; but if anything isn't exactly how you need it, you should be able to tweak it to your requirements. Hope this helps!

```
Sub AlternateRowColors()
    Dim LastRow As Long

    With ActiveSheet
        'LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End With

    LastRowNew = LastRow - 8
    If LastRowNew < 5 Then LastRowNew = 5

    For Each Cell In Range("A5:x" & LastRowNew) ''change range accordingly
        If Cell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then ''highlights row 2,4,6 etc|= 0 highlights 1,3,5
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 15 ''color to preference
        Else
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone ''color to preference or remove
        End If
    Next Cell

    Range("A" & (LastRow + 2), Range("X" & (LastRow + 5))).Interior.ColorIndex = 45

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you that worked for the alternate row color. Is there a way to add an offset so that the last 8 rows will not have the alternate row color? I discovered that the row below the "LastRow" is a merged row and would not be highlighted, but the next 4 rows will have a different highlight color.

Comment: I've added two extra lines above that will prevent the last 8 rows being highlighted. Also, you say the row beneath the LastRow is merged (do you mean multiple columns of cells on the single row are merged?), and the next four rows will have a different highlight color... do you mean that'll be the case already? Or do you need to code that here too?

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. The row beneath the LastRow is merged with multiple columns from A:X. I need the code for the last four rows as well.

Comment: I've added another version above under 'additional edit 2', check it out, hopefully that's what you need. If not, you should be able to tweak it to your requirements.

Comment: Thank you David for all of your assistance. I will need to do some tweaking, but you certainly have more than gotten me in the right direction. Now it is time for me to learn more about this script. Thank you.