# VBA Shade Alternate Rows

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

Using [this](http://www.learnexcelmacro.com/wp/excel-macro-tutorial/) site as a source, I've put together [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8adwshyh2ga4fy/Copy%20of%20Download%20File%20Orignal%20Development6.xlsm?dl=0) workbook which extracts and lists files from a given folder.

The code works fine, but I'm trying to adapt this a little by shading the alternate rows in columns C, D and E.

I've researched this and found an example [here](http://msgroups.net/microsoft.public.excel.programming/row-striping-with-vba/53482)

The problem I've got is that I can only manage to shade column `E` and I'm not sure why. I'd also like to shade the alternate row, but I'm a little unsure about how to go about it.

This is the code which extracts the files and shades the rows.

```
Public Sub ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)
    Dim lngLastRow As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        ' display file properties
        Cells(iRow, 3).Formula = iRow - 13
        Cells(iRow, 4).Formula = FileItem.Name
        Cells(iRow, 5).Select
        Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        FileItem.Path, TextToDisplay:="Click Here to Open"
        iRow = iRow + 1 ' next row number

        lngLastRow = Sh.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
        Range("C14:E" & lngLastRow).Activate
        Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
        Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=MOD(ROW(),2)=0"

        Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 24

    Next FileItem

    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder, True
        Next SubFolder
    End If
    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

I just wondered whether someone may be able to look at this please and let me know where I've gone wrong.

Comment: Not everyone can access Dropbox from their work environment, and it's possible/likely you will delete the file from there when you get your question answered. You would do well to post the relevant code in your question to provide the lasting relevance we're looking for at SO. A classic case of commenting while post-editing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those of who are interested this is my working code:

Public Sub ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)

```
    Dim LastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
        ' display file properties
        Cells(iRow, 3).Formula = iRow - 12
        Cells(iRow, 4).Formula = FileItem.Name
        Cells(iRow, 5).Select
        Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
        FileItem.Path, TextToDisplay:="Click Here to Open"
        iRow = iRow + 1 ' next row number

        With ActiveSheet
            LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
            LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
        End With

        For Each Cell In Range("C13:E" & LastRow) ''change range accordingly
            If Cell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then ''highlights row 2,4,6 etc|= 0 highlights 1,3,5
                Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(232, 232, 232) ''color to preference
            Else
                Cell.Interior.Color = RGB(141, 180, 226) 'color to preference or remove
            End If
        Next Cell
    Next FileItem

    If IncludeSubfolders Then
        For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
            ListFilesInFolder SubFolder, True
        Next SubFolder
    End If
    Set FileItem = Nothing
    Set SourceFolder = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try, look for the "add" comments. Also, note that I just picked another color for the other color stripe - you can change it to suit your needs.

```
Public Sub ListFilesInFolder(SourceFolder As Scripting.folder, _
           IncludeSubfolders As Boolean)
Dim lngLastRow As Long
Dim Toggle as integer           'added this here

On Error Resume Next
Toggle = 0
For Each FileItem In SourceFolder.Files
' display file properties
    Cells(iRow, 3).Formula = iRow - 13
    Cells(iRow, 4).Formula = FileItem.Name
    Cells(iRow, 5).Select
    Selection.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
          FileItem.Path, TextToDisplay:="Click Here to Open"
    iRow = iRow + 1 ' next row number
    lngLastRow = Sh.Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("C14:E" & lngLastRow).Activate
    Selection.FormatConditions.Delete
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
               Formula1:="=MOD(ROW(),2)=0"
    '-----------------------------------
    'Add this section here
    if toggle = 0 then
      Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 24
      toggle = 1
    Else
      Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior.ColorIndex = 42
      toggle = 0
    end if

Next FileItem

If IncludeSubfolders Then
    For Each SubFolder In SourceFolder.SubFolders
        ListFilesInFolder SubFolder, True
    Next SubFolder
End If
Set FileItem = Nothing
Set SourceFolder = Nothing
Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi @Freeman, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post and for the comment on the 'Dropbox' file.

Thank you also for the code. I've tried this, but unfortunately the second cell is not shaded. Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: Ah, I just realized what you were doing. Ignore all the changes I suggested. Manually check on a cell  that you've modified to see how many `FormatConditions` there are on it. My guess is that you're setting the `Interior.ColorIndex` of the wrong one. Either there are multiples, or the index should be `(0)`.

Comment: Hi @Freeman, I just wanted to let you that I solved the problem using [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23711615/excel-2010-vba-alternate-row-color-on-changing-range-starting-with-a5). Many thanks and kind regards. Chris

Comment: Fantastic @IRHM! Glad you found a solution. That's essentially what I was getting at, unfortunately, I had a mixture of your conditional formatting and my explicit formatting and that was creating issues. I would suggest you put your final code in as an answer and come back later to accept it. That will help the next person who comes along and finds your post - it's easier to see a marked answer instead of discovering it buried in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, you don't need the formula in the cells to create a VBA-controlled alternate shading scheme. Without the file directory code, I created a quick routine to shade alternate lines for only columns C, D, and E.

If you can remove your FormatConditions code from your routine above, this may be an acceptable substitute.

```
Sub ReShade(startRow As Integer, endRow As Integer)
    '--- begin by "erasing" the previous row coloring
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(startRow, 3), Cells(endRow, 5)).Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    '--- shades alternate rows in columnd C, D, E
    Dim r As Integer
    Dim rowCells As Range
    For r = startRow To endRow Step 2
        Set rowCells = ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(r, 3), Cells(r, 5))
        With rowCells
            .Interior.ColorIndex = 24
        End With
    Next r
End Sub

'--- call ReShade at the end of your routine, as in...
Sub test()
    ReShade 5, 20  
End Sub
```